# Import Packages are not working/red underline. (Flutter) (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, import, package

trying to use some packages and for some reason they aren't working/I am getting a red underline on each of them. Any answer on why this could be happening? as well as if there is a solution that could be provided, that would be much appreciated! I am new to this all and still learning!

For this set of code, the ones that are underlined would be
the logger package, dio package, and units package.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:simple_gradient_text/simple_gradient_text.dart';
import '../utils/dreams_utils.dart';


class ResourcesPage extends StatefulWidget{

@override
_ResourcesPageState createState() => _ResourcesPageState();
}

class _ResourcesPageState extends State<ResourcesPage> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: GradientText('Sleep Resources',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0,),
        colors: [colorStyle("gradient1"), colorStyle("gradient2"),
          colorStyle("gradient3"), colorStyle("gradient2"),
          colorStyle("gradient1")]
    ),
    backgroundColor: colorStyle("appHeader"),
  ),
  backgroundColor: colorStyle("appBackground"),
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,


  body: Center(
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,

      children: <Widget>[

        new Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: new Card(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 400.0,
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset("assets/images/SleepF.jpeg",
                  height: 400,
                  width: 400,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new InkWell(
                      child: new Text('Sleep Foundation',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: colorStyle("main"),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                      onTap: () => launch('https://www.sleepfoundation.org/sleep-hygiene/healthy-sleep-tips')
                  ),
                ),
                Text('We work hard to bring you the most accurate and up-to-date information about different sleep health topics. Rest assured every Sleep Foundation guide is carefully vetted and fact-checked prior to publication.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: colorStyle("main"),
                      fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),


        new Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: new Card(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 400.0,
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset("assets/images/IFFA.png",
                  height: 400,
                  width: 400,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new InkWell(
                      child: new Text('International Functional Foods Association',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: colorStyle("main"),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                      onTap: () => launch('https://iffassociation.org/learn/how-functional-foods-may-improve-sleep-and-immune-health?gclid=Cj0KCQiAys2MBhDOARIsAFf1D1eHFvfuovsyweVETX8I5DOztdqM_QmIN_1DjOtkDNOiKlHIn9RN1bAaAhsLEALw_wcB')
                  ),
                ),
                Text('We exist to ensure everyone, everywhere has an equal chance to take control of their own health and wellness.  Functional foods are an important component of healthy, nutritious diets. A diet rich in functional foods promotes a healthy body, as well as a healthy mind.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: colorStyle("main"),
                      fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

        new Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: new Card(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 400.0,
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset("assets/images/Kaiser.png",
                  height: 400,
                  width: 400,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new InkWell(
                      child: new Text('Kaiser Permanente',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: colorStyle("main"),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                      onTap: () => launch('https://healthengagement.kaiserpermanente.org/wellness-topics/sleep/')
                  ),
                ),
                Text('We help people reach their health goals, by listening, supporting and guiding, so they can live their best lives.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: colorStyle("main"),
                      fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

        new Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: new Card(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 400.0,
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset("assets/images/JHM.jpeg",
                  height: 400,
                  width: 400,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new InkWell(
                      child: new Text('John Hopkins Medical',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: colorStyle("main"),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                      onTap: () => launch('https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/wellness-and-prevention/sleep')
                  ),
                ),
                Text('At Johns Hopkins Medicine, your health and safety are our very highest priorities. We are ready to care for you and your family in our hospitals, surgery centers, and through in-person clinic and online video visits. Learn how we are keeping you safe and protected so that you can get the care you need.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: colorStyle("main"),
                      fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

        new Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: new Card(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 400.0,
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset("assets/images/BMI.png",
                  height: 400,
                  width: 400,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new InkWell(
                      child: new Text('Beautiful Mind International',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: colorStyle("main"),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                      onTap: () => launch('https://beauty-mind.org/sleep-guru/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAys2MBhDOARIsAFf1D1czPDb4ROkA_dhket7YAZrPB9H7AK4OqEclcbTaiU_OgDq9odhQ7x8aAhz7EALw_wcB')
                  ),
                ),
                Text('Beautiful Mind International project aims to educate people what is mental health, its issues, and ways to overcome them.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: colorStyle("main"),
                      fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

        new Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: new Card(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 400.0,
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset("assets/images/CDC.png",
                  height: 400,
                  width: 400,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new InkWell(
                      child: new Text('Centers for Disease Control and Prevention',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: colorStyle("main"),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                      onTap: () => launch('https://www.cdc.gov/sleep/index.html')
                  ),
                ),
                Text('The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention is the national public health agency of the United States.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: colorStyle("main"),
                      fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

        new Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: new Card(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 400.0,
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset("assets/images/sleepnum1.jpeg",
                  height: 400,
                  width: 400,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new InkWell(
                      child: new Text('Sleep Number',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: colorStyle("main"),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                      onTap: () => launch('https://www.sleepnumber.com/categories/beds-on-sale?acid=psnonbrand&ascid=Google%2BNational-_-google-_-NB_Number_Bed-_-Number_Bed_Exact-_-516451220073-_-b-_-kwd-846217698-_-mediacode-_-Beds-_-1&key=number%20beds&s_kwcid=AL!6200!3!516451220073!b!!g!!number%20beds&k_clickid=go_cmp-193921164_adg-14393203044_ad-516451220073_kwd-846217698_dev-c_ext-_prd-&gclid=Cj0KCQiAys2MBhDOARIsAFf1D1d4C7oDgf9l_gikrEEVbK2Y7EpcHjg8AvPAmFGam3Qgjgc-XknDyYYaAtNfEALw_wcB')
                  ),
                ),
                Text('Sleep Number is an American manufacturer that makes the Sleep Number and Comfortaire beds, as well as foundations and bedding accessories. The company is based in Minneapolis, Minnesota. In addition to its Minnesota headquarters, Sleep Number has manufacturing and distribution facilities in South Carolina and Utah.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: colorStyle("main"),
                      fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

        new Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: new Card(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 400.0,
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset("assets/images/sunset.jpeg",
                  height: 400,
                  width: 400,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new InkWell(
                      child: new Text('UMN Duluth Health Services',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: colorStyle("main"),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                      onTap: () => launch('https://health-services.d.umn.edu/health-education/sleep-education-initiatives')
                  ),
                ),
                Text('Health Education Staff, Interns, and our previous student health advisory committee developed and administered an informal needs assessment to measure student reported barriers to sleep and methods for sleep support that students would use.  We learned a lot and are putting that information into practice with a series of initiatives on campus.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: colorStyle("main"),
                      fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

      ],
    ),
  ),
);

}
}
```

For this set of code, the ones that are underlined in red would be the
units package, dio package, and logger package.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:units/dreams/utils/dreams_constant.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
 import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import "package:units/api.dart";



  List<dynamic> calculator(double hour, double minute, double sleepHour, double 
  sleepMinute, 
  UnitType uniType, UnitType unitTypeTime) {

  List result = new List.filled(3, null, growable: false);
  double tempHour = 0.0;
  double tempMinute = 0.00;

  if(uniType == UnitType.BED) {
 tempHour = hour + sleepHour;
  tempMinute = minute + sleepMinute;

  if (tempMinute >= 60) {
  tempMinute -= 60;
  tempHour += 1;
   }
 }
 if (uniType == UnitType.WAKE) {
tempHour = hour - sleepHour;
tempMinute = minute - sleepMinute;

if(tempMinute < 0){
  tempMinute += 60.00;
  tempHour -= 1;
  }
}

if(tempHour > 12 || tempHour < 0) {
switch(unitTypeTime) {
  case UnitType.AM: { unitTypeTime = UnitType.PM; }
  break;
  case UnitType.PM: { unitTypeTime = UnitType.AM; }
  break;
  default: {}
  break;
}

tempHour %= 12;
   }
  if(tempHour ==0){
  tempHour = 12;
  }



 //result = tempHour + (tempMinute/100);
 result[0] = (tempHour + (tempMinute/100));
 result[1] = unitTypeTime;
 result[2] = uniType;

return result;
}

bool isEmptyString(String string){
return string == null || string.length == 0;
}

Future<int> loadValue() async{
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
int? data = preferences.getInt('data');
if( data != null ) {
return data;
} else {
return 0;
}

}

void saveValue(int value) async{
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
preferences.setInt('data', value);
}

void setThemeKey(int color) async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setInt('theme', color); 
}

Future<int?> getThemeKey() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final color = prefs.getInt('theme');
return color;
}

void setTheme(int theme){
switch(theme) {
case 1: {  defaultTheme(); }
break;

case 2: {  monochromeTheme(); }
break;

case 3: {  pinkTheme(); }
break;

case 4: {  sherbetTheme(); }
break;

case 5: {  thunderTheme(); }
break;

case 6: {  redTheme(); }
break;

case 7: {  transTheme(); }
break;

case 8: { enbyTheme(); }
break;

default: { defaultTheme(); }
break;
}
}

Color mains = Colors.white60;
Color accent = Colors.cyan;
Color widgets = Colors.blueGrey.shade700;
Color gradient1 = Colors.cyan.shade900;
Color gradient2 = Colors.cyan.shade700;
Color gradient3 = Colors.cyan.shade500;
Color appHeader = Colors.blueGrey.shade900;
Color appBackground = Colors.blueGrey.shade800;

Future<int> defaultTheme() async {
mains = Colors.white60;
accent = Colors.cyan;
widgets = Colors.blueGrey.shade700;
gradient1 = Colors.cyan.shade900;
gradient2 = Colors.cyan.shade700;
gradient3 = Colors.cyan.shade500;
appHeader = Colors.blueGrey.shade900;
appBackground = Colors.blueGrey.shade800;
return 1;
}
Future<int> monochromeTheme() async {
mains = Colors.black;
accent = Colors.grey.shade700;
widgets = Colors.grey;
gradient1 = Colors.grey.shade700;
gradient2 = Colors.grey.shade500;
gradient3 = Colors.grey.shade300;
appHeader = Colors.grey.shade900;
appBackground = Colors.grey.shade800;
return 1;
}
Future<int> pinkTheme() async {
mains = Colors.pink.shade500;
accent = Colors.pink;
widgets = Colors.pink.shade200;
gradient1 = Colors.pinkAccent.shade700;
gradient2 = Colors.pinkAccent.shade400;
gradient3 = Colors.pinkAccent;
appHeader = Colors.pink.shade900;
appBackground = Colors.pink.shade800;
return 1;
}
Future<int> sherbetTheme() async {
mains = Colors.deepOrange;
accent = Colors.green.shade300;
widgets = Colors.yellow.shade100;
gradient1 = Colors.purpleAccent.shade400;
gradient2 = Colors.orangeAccent.shade100;
gradient3 = Colors.cyanAccent;
appHeader = Colors.pink.shade300;
appBackground = Colors.pink.shade100;
return 1;
}
Future<int> thunderTheme() async {
mains = Colors.yellow;
accent = Colors.yellowAccent;
widgets = Colors.grey.shade700;
gradient1 = Colors.cyan.shade500;
gradient2 = Colors.yellow.shade700;
gradient3 = Colors.yellow.shade200;
appHeader = Colors.grey.shade900;
appBackground = Colors.grey.shade800;
return 1;
}
Future<int> redTheme() async {
mains = Colors.red.shade900;
accent = Colors.red.shade900;
widgets = Colors.white70;
gradient1 = Colors.red.shade900;
gradient2 = Colors.red.shade700;
gradient3 = Colors.red.shade500;
appHeader = Colors.grey.shade500;
appBackground = Colors.grey.shade200;
return 1;
}
Future<int> transTheme() async {
mains = Colors.blue;
accent = Colors.pink;
widgets = Colors.white70;
gradient1 = Colors.lightBlue.shade200;
gradient2 = Colors.pinkAccent.shade100;
gradient3 = Colors.white;
appHeader = Colors.blue.shade800;
appBackground = Colors.pinkAccent.shade100;
return 1;
}
Future<int> enbyTheme() async {
mains = Colors.black;
accent = Colors.yellow.shade700;
widgets = Colors.white;
gradient1 = Colors.black;
gradient2 = Colors.yellow;
gradient3 = Colors.white;
appHeader = Colors.purple;
appBackground = Colors.purple.shade200;
return 1;
}

Color colorStyle(String color){
switch(color){
case "main":
  return mains;
case "accent":
  return accent;
case "widgets":
  return widgets;
case "gradient1":
  return gradient1;
case "gradient2":
  return gradient2;
case "gradient3":
  return gradient3;
case "appHeader":
  return appHeader;
case "appBackground":
  return appBackground;
default:
  return Colors.purpleAccent;
}
}
```

This is the error code that I am getting

Invalid depfile: C:\Users\Mahjur - Coding\Desktop\SweetDreams-X.2.dart_tool\flutter_build\e98d11342ddd14555bbca12c2fd83e4a\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\Mahjur - Coding\Desktop\SweetDreams-X.2.dart_tool\flutter_build\e98d11342ddd14555bbca12c2fd83e4a\kernel_snapshot.d
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'logger' in 'package:logger/logger.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'dio' in 'package:dio/dio.dart'.
lib/dreams/utils/dreams_utils.dart:7:8: Error: Not found: 'package:logger/logger.dart'
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
^
lib/dreams/utils/dreams_utils.dart:8:8: Error: Not found: 'package:dio/dio.dart'
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
^
lib/dreams/utils/dreams_utils.dart:9:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/api.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

import "package:units/api.dart";
^

Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: units
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally  
published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private 
packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to 
pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your 
application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 
1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in 
flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, 
respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build- 
number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at 
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while 
build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
#
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
shared_preferences: ^2.0.6

 # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your 
 application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
   firebase_core: ^1.13.1
 firebase_auth: ^3.3.11
 cloud_firestore: ^3.1.10
 modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
 firebase_messaging: ^11.2.11
 firebase_analytics: ^9.1.2
 flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
 flutter_local_notifications: ^9.4.0
 #flutter_native_timezone: ^1.1.0
 rxdart: ^0.27.1
 #awesome_notifications: ^0.6.21

   dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter

  # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see 
  the
  # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

  # The following section is specific to Flutter.
  flutter:

   # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons 
  in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, 
 like 
  this:
  assets:
 - lib/assests/images/
 - android/app/src/main/res/drawable/

  # -lib/dreams/images/app_icon.png
   # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific 
  "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

    # For details regarding adding assets from package 
       dependencies, 
     see
    # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

   # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section 
     here,
      # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should 
    have a
   # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key 
    with a
    # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. 
   For
   # example:
   # fonts:
   #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
 #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
 #         style: italic
 #   - family: Trajan Pro
 #     fonts:
 #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
 #         weight: 700
 #
 # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
 # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: try run `flutter pub get` on your project folder

Comment: could you add what error you are getting?

Comment: I've already tried running that, but that doesn't solve my issue unfortunately.

Comment: Updated the post, now you can see the error that I am experiencing

Comment: Try doing `flutter clean` and than `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run in the command line

```
flutter clean
```

then

```
flutter pub get
```

if that doesn't help, shut down and restart android studio and the file.

if that doesn't help delete the dependency from the pubspec.yaml run pub get, then re-add the dependency and run pub get, sometimes you have to hit flutter over the head with a hammer.

double check the packages you are having issues with are actually added in the pubspec.yaml and ensure there is not a # infront of them that comments them out

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately still no fix.

Comment: That is frustrating, have you ensured you are running the latest package version? Mind sharing your pubspec.yaml

Comment: I believe so? I'm not 100% sure how to check that. But i've updated my post and now you can see my pubsec.yaml at the bottom

Comment: it doesnt look like your packages are in the pubspec.yaml that would be why you are getting the red underlines

Comment: I'm so dumb haha! Thank you!, added the dependencies and now it is working. Whole time I thought it was in there. Thanks again.

Comment: Ive done worse! Glad we figured it out!